# AJAX separating the data returned into specific DIVs

Tags: ajax, parsing, variables, html

AJAX code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function doCalc(){
            var roomX = $('#room_str').val();
            var heightX = $('#height_str').val();
            var widthX = $('#width_str').val();
            var prodid = $('#prodid').val();
            var qtyX = $('#qty_str').val();

            $.post('db_query.php',
            {qtyX:qtyX, roomX:roomX, heightX:heightX, widthX:widthX, prodid:prodid}, 
            function(data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#width-placeholder').html(data.width);
                $('#height-placeholder').html(data.height);
                // ...
            });
            return false;
            };
        </script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include('db_pbconnection.php');
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM price_dimensions WHERE prodid = '".$_POST['prodid']."' AND height >= '".$_POST['heightX']."' AND width >= '".$_POST['widthX']."' ORDER BY height ASC, width ASC LIMIT 1 ");
$results = array();
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$results = array(
   'width' => $row['width'],
   'height' => $row['height'],
   'price' => $row['price']
);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
?>
```

EDIT:  Updated code works successfully thanks to Alex.  This uses json_encode to send the data back with ability to assign each SQL row to an identified  for placeholders.  This is just in case you need to move your data around individually in a layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, what you try to do is apply selectors to HTML data coming from AJAX request. Yes? I don't think jQuery would help you here.

An option might be to have this div structure already on page as some template with placeholders. And your AJAX calls should return data in JavaScript native, parsable format - [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). PHP has a function which will make JSON for you - [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). After you get JSON from your server, you can do this:

```
function(data) {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#width-placeholder').html(data.width);
    $('#height-placeholder').html(data.height);
    // ...
});
return false;
};
```

Comment: Is this part (data.width) where it says "width" the php database value?  I'm learning json_encode and I'm assuming this is what will convert my SELECT query into usable data for your code above?  Will I need to use "success:" in the script to show the results?  Or does that happen because of the fact your code is somehow assigning the retrieved data to <div id="width-placeholder">  ?

Comment: if you `json_encode` an array like `array('width'=>500, 'height'=>200, ...)`, then in JS you can use `data.width`. So check what your sql query returns (`var_dump` it). Yes, you will need `success` callback, because AJAX calls are async (or you can use `$.post(url, data, successCallback)`).

Comment: Thanks to your help I'm incredibly close to finishing this and sleeping after a week of confusion.  You're very clear in your answers.  I've added new EDIT of my changes and it still isn't working.  I have a feeling one of the tags, values, or labels isn't matching between the php page and the ajax script.

Comment: Is it a typo? You forgot to `echo $json; ` to make it work (at the very end).

Comment: And your `$results` should be filled other way. You select only one row, so there is no need to use `while` loop. I'll suggest an edit in a moment.

Comment: Thank you but it still isn't working.  I'll keep checking on any typos on my end.  I really appreciate this.  Are you for hire or is that unethical to ask on this forum?  If so, I apologize.

Comment: Please try doing `var_dump($row);` and `var_dump($results);` to see what your sql query returns.

Comment: It works!  I removed this:  
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    $data = array();
    include 'db_pbconnection.php';
and replaced with this...
    include('db_pbconnection.php');
maybe something was conflicting above or maybe the connection string wasn't typed correctly?  I used it from a demo on json.